# correct usage of preposition 'on' and 'with'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

which of the following sentence is correct and why?

> 1.The principal started his lecture **with** a pessimistic note.
>
> 2.The principal started his lecture **on** a pessimistic note

Comment: They're both "valid", but idiomatically we usually use ***on*** in this exact context. Note that the actual syntax of #2 could in principle reflect the fact that the ***subject*** of the lecture was "a pessimistic note" - but without convincing context supporting that somewhat perverse interpretation, we can reasonably rule it out. Just as we can ignore the possibility that the ***with*** version means he introduced some contextually relevant "pessimistic note" before launching into the substance of his lecture.

Answer (score -2):

Both are fine but "with a note" usage is more according to this.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+a+note%2Con+a+note&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20note%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20note%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This doesn’t hold when there is an adjective before the word “note”.

Comment: @Mixolydian explaination?

Comment: Not sure I have a good explanation but I’ll try- saying “on a note” (no adj) doesn’t mean anything in most contexts. You must include an adjective because you’re describing a mood- “on a sad note”, “on a happy note”, “on a happier note” are common expressions that are used to show that something has a certain mood (“happy”, “sad”, “pessimistic”, etc.). “On that note” is a related phrase and requires no adjective but “that note” refers to the mood of what was said previously. See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44506/meaning-of-on-that-note-and-how-do-you-use-it